# Debugging bookmarklets in Firefox

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, bookmarklet

I would like to debug bookmarklets. How can I do this? Preferably in Firefox.

Bookmarklets has only one line of code so direct debugging them is impracticable.

If I create "script" tag with code which I send from bookmarklet, code from this "script" tag isn't listed on Firebug scripts... (this code run properly, only can't debugging)

Alternatively, If there is a possibility to debug code typed in a console, it will be OK too.

Answer (score 4):

Make a bookmarklet like this:

`javascript:document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).setAttribute('src','http://localhost/test.js');void(0);`

It would automatically appear in Firebug, as simple as that.
(Assuming you have recent versions of Firefox and Firebug)

Use you development version of code in the `test.js` file and use `debugger;` or insert the breakpoints manually.

Extra note:
If you face problems like your code works in development mode (by including file as mentioned above) but does not work when it is converted to a single line bookmarklet, then there must be a problem in the conversion/encoding you did to make it single line.

Comment: Thanks for proposal, it works! However, there is one minus in my case because I create tool to generate bookmarklets (from userscripts) so to debug them I have to show a content of bookmarklet, copy to a file and then I can debug.

Comment: Is it that you want to debug the bookmarklet in its original form, ie, debug the single line of code? I'm a bit confused by the last comment! What are the other things that you are looking for resolving your requirement?

Answer (score 2):

Paste your bookmarklet into the developer console, but before you execute it, add a `debugger;` statement on the first line. The bookmarklet will appear in the debugger under a tab called "SOURCE".

Answer (score 0):

copy & paste your bookmarklet code into the debugger console, press 'enter'

by "code" I mean

```
function(){ ... }();
```

any loaded javascript files will appear in the debugger tab, where you can set breakpoints, step through etc. when you paste (or up arrow in console) and press 'enter' a second time.